# Is there a way to get the function type of a pointer to a member function?

Tags: c++, function, types, std-function

If you have a pointer to a member function like so:

```
struct Foo {  void func() {}  };

void(Foo::*funcPtr)() = &Foo::func;
```

Is there a way to get the type of the function, with the `Foo::` removed?

I.e.,

`void(Foo::*)()` -> `void(*)()`

`int(Foo::*)(int, double, float)` -> `int(*)(int, double, float)`

You get the idea.

The goal is to make `std::function` accept a functor like this:

```
struct Functor { void operator()(...){} }

Functor f;
std::function< magic_get_function_type< decltype(Functor::operator()) >::type > stdfunc{f};
```

Is it possible?

Comment: FWIW, If you have C++17 you should just be able to do `auto stdfunc = std::function{Functor{}};`

Comment: Related-ish: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28509563/4641116

Comment: You can also use lambdas: `std::function f = []() { /*do stuff*/ };`

Comment: @NathanOliver Wow. I had somehow gotten the idea that `std::function` cannot deduce its template arguments, and I have as a result been trying to solve non-existent problems for the past week. My past four questions on SO (one of which you answered) have all revolved around this. Feeling a bit silly now.

Comment: @JensB Don't feel too bad.  This was a feature that was added to C++ starting with C++17.  For more reading on it, lookup Class Template Argument Deduction (CTAD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, it is possible with a simple template:

```cpp
template <typename Return, typename Class, typename... Args>
Return(*GetSig(Return(Class::*)(Args...)))(Args...);
```

This defines a function called `GetSig` that takes as parameter a member function pointer and essentially extracts the `Return` type and the `Args...` and returns it as a non-member function pointer.

Example usage:

```cpp
class C;
int main() {
    using FuncType = int(C::*)(double, float);
    FuncType member_pointer;
    decltype(GetSigType(member_pointer)) new_pointer;
    // new_pointer is now of type int(*)(double, float) instead of
    // int(C::*)(double, float)
}
```