# c++ Extract parameter type list from function pointer

Tags: c++, function, templates, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

Im trying to get the argument types from a function pointer

This should be the working end product

```
std::function<void(TestAppObject*, MemberFuncArgs<decltype(&TestAppObject::TestMethod)>::InputArgs)> func = &TestAppObject::TestMethod;
```

Current MemberFuncArgs class

```
template<typename T>
struct MemberFuncArgs;

template<typename RT, typename Owner, typename ...Args>
struct MemberFuncArgs<RT(Owner::*)(Args...)>
{
    static const size_t ArgCount = sizeof...(Args);
    typedef RT ReturnType;
    typedef Args InputArgs;
};
```

Compiler throws the error `'Args': parameter pack must be expanded in this context`.

I just need a way to extract the `Args...` type from the function pointer, its probably just a syntax issue that im too dumb to see...

Comment: You can't do this. You have to let your member function type trait have a meta function adding arguments to a function type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler say the you can't define a single type `InputArgs`

```
typedef Args InputArgs;
```

given that `Args` is a variadic list.

Maybe you can define a type base on a tuple

```
using InArgsTuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
```

so you can extract the single types in `Args...` using `std::tuple_element`

So, with a little template meta-programming, you should be able to write something as

```
using TplT = MemberFuncArgs<decltype(&TestAppObject::TestMethod)>::InArgsTuple;

std::function<void(TestAppObject*, typename std::tuple_element<Is, TplT>::type ...)>
   func = &TestAppObject::TestMethod;
```

assuming that `Is...` is a variadic sequence of template integer values from zero to `sizeof...(Args)-1`.

The following is a full compiling C++20 example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

struct TestAppObject
{
  int TestMethod (char, short, int, long, long long)
  { return 0; }
};

template <typename T>
struct MemberFuncArgs;

template <typename RT, typename Owner, typename ... Args>
struct MemberFuncArgs<RT(Owner::*)(Args...)>
{
  static constexpr std::size_t ArgCount = sizeof...(Args);

  using ReturnType  = RT;
  using InArgsTuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
};
    
int main()
{
  using MFA  = MemberFuncArgs<decltype(&TestAppObject::TestMethod)>;
  using FunT = decltype([]<std::size_t ... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
     -> std::function<void(TestAppObject*,
           typename std::tuple_element<Is, MFA::InArgsTuple>::type ...)>
     { return {}; }
     (std::make_index_sequence<MFA::ArgCount>{}));

  FunT  func = &TestAppObject::TestMethod;
}
```

If you can't use C++20 (so no template lambda and no lambda in not evaluated context) you can substitute the lambda with a traditional template function, only declared (because is used only inside `decltype()`.

The following is a full compiling C++14/C++17 example.
#include 
#include

```
struct TestAppObject
{
  int TestMethod (char, short, int, long, long long)
  { return 0; }
};

template <typename T>
struct MemberFuncArgs;

template <typename RT, typename Owner, typename ... Args>
struct MemberFuncArgs<RT(Owner::*)(Args...)>
{
  static constexpr std::size_t ArgCount = sizeof...(Args);

  using ReturnType  = RT;
  using InArgsTuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template <typename MFA, std::size_t ... Is>
std::function<void(TestAppObject*,
   typename std::tuple_element<Is, typename MFA::InArgsTuple>::type ...)>
      extra_function (std::index_sequence<Is...>);

int main()
{
  using MFA  = MemberFuncArgs<decltype(&TestAppObject::TestMethod)>;
  using FunT = decltype(extra_function<MFA>
                           (std::make_index_sequence<MFA::ArgCount>{}));

  FunT  func = &TestAppObject::TestMethod;
}
```

Comment: How would I generate that sequence of integers?

Comment: @DarxDev - Give me some minutes and I'll show an example

Comment: @DarxDev - full C++20 compilable example added.

Comment: could you make it compatible with C++17?

Comment: @DarxDev - yes... but I need an external function... only declared, not defined... give me some minutes.

Comment: @DarxDev - Added a C++14/C++17 example.

Comment: you're a real G man (:

Comment: Don't you need const/volatile/ref/noexcept qualifier specializations in order to cover all types of member functions? Do you happen to know if there is any other way than writing a tedious amount of bloaty template code to deal with this problem in C++20?

Comment: @303 - Well... the point of the question is another (manage the types extracted from a function signature) so I suppose the OP the type of method signature that he needs. But, yes, you're right: to cover all types of methods requires a lot of repetitive work. And no, I don't know a C++20 way to avoid it.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. I think I asked my question a bit poorly because I didn't mean to imply that your answer was in some way incomplete or lacking. Unfortunately, I happen to run into this problem about retrieving argument types of member functions quite often and it is rather surprising that there is no straight forward way of dealing with it in modern C++.

Answer (score 0):

See my response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76253527/698767.) (and the link I cited there, a fully-documented open source solution for this type of situation - you can *easily* retrieve the traits for any function including parameter types). In your case you may be after the "ArgTypes_t" helper template briefly seen in the latter link, but fully documented at the link I cited there (but in practice few need to access "ArgTypes_t" - most will typically target "ArgType_t" instead (without the "s"). The docs explain it all.