# Define a function signature containing a reference with C++20 Concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to use C++20 Concepts to constrain an interface. In this interface, I want a function signature to only use references. For some reason, I can't do this. Would someone help?

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
concept MyInterface = requires(T t)
{
    // How do I specify a f(int&) instead of f(int) here?
    {t.f(int{})} -> std::integral;
};

struct X
{
    int f(int& i) { 
       return i; 
    }
};
static_assert(MyInterface<X>);


/*
** While tempting, this is _NOT_ a solution. **
template <typename T>
concept MyInterface = requires(T t, int& i) // Add a requirement here.
{
    {t.f(i)} -> std::integral;
};

// This will compile, despite allowing `i` to be an int. 
// When really, it should be a int&.
X::f(int i) { return i };
*/
```

Comment: "*I want a function signature to only use references.*" Concepts are not base classes. You do not dictate what a function signature must be; you specify what *behavior* is required. What behavior is it that you need from this function? Why do you want it to be an error to take the parameter by value?

Comment: Requirements in requres clause are basically checking *how it can be used*, not *how it is defined*. If you want to specify the signature, you have to perform checking on signature. Have a look at [Get types of C++ function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28509563/13456180).

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with this comment, this is absolutely a solution (except you don't have to make `i` an `int&`, `int` suffices):

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept MyInterface = requires(T t, int i)
{
    {t.f(i)} -> std::integral;
};
```

That is, indeed, your interface: you're passing an lvalue `int` into the member function `f` and you expect it to return some type which satisfies `integral`.

---

In order to reject callees taking `int`, you have to either pass some different type - like something convertible to `int&` instead of directly that:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept MyInterface = requires(T t, std::reference_wrapper<int> i)
{
    {t.f(i)} -> std::integral;
};
```

or then additionally reject the other case:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept MyInterface =
    requires(T t, int i) { {t.f(i)} -> std::integral; }
    && !requires(T t){ t.f(42); };
```

Passing `reference_wrapper<int>` is... ok. Explicitly rejecting taking `int` rvalues seems questionable at best.

Answer (score -1):

You can utilize `std::declval` to create a reference type for the constraint:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept MyInterface = requires(T t)
{
    {t.f(std::declval<int&>())} -> std::integral;
};
```

Note that this would still allow `T::f(int)` to work. To disallow it, you can add another constraint to it:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept MyInterface = requires(T t)
{
    {t.f(std::declval<int&>())} -> std::integral;
}
&& !requires(T t)
{
    {t.f(std::declval<int>())} -> std::integral;
};
```