# C++ function pointer and templated argument used with separate template

Tags: c++, templates, arguments

I'm trying to pass a single function pointer argument to a function which then uses the function's parameter as one argument of a function template and the actual function pointer as another template argument.

I'm trying to simplify some entt event registration code but I've hit a wall.
The default entt code looks like this

```
dispatcher.sink<Event>().connect<&Func>();
```

`Event` is very basic and just looks like this:

```
class Event
{
public:
    std::string state;
};
```

`Func` has a definition like

```
void Func(const Event& event)
{
    std::cout << "EVENT: " << event.state << '\n';
}
```

Because `Func` already has `Event` I thought I might be able to simplify this code by just using Func but I'm not sure how.

I've gotten it to look like

```
registerEvent<Event, &OnEvent>();
```

With

```
template <typename EventType, void(*fnPtr)(const EventType&)>
void registerEvent() {
    dispatcher.sink<EventType>().template connect<fnPtr>();
}
```

But I was hoping to make it smaller like:

```
registerEvent<&OnEvent>();
```

or

```
registerEvent(&OnEvent);
```

Here is a godbolt link with all the code: https://godbolt.org/z/n3a5YKGhz

or here:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "entt/entt.hpp"

static entt::dispatcher dispatcher;

template <typename EventType, void(*fnPtr)(const EventType&)>
void registerEvent() {
    dispatcher.sink<EventType>().template connect<fnPtr>();
}

template <typename EventType>
void registerEventSmall(void(*fnPtr)(const EventType&)) {
    dispatcher.sink<EventType>().template connect<fnPtr>();
}

class Event
{
public:
    std::string state;
};

void OnEvent(const Event& event)
{
    std::cout << "EVENT: " << event.state << '\n';
}

void OnEvent2(const Event& event)
{
    std::cout << "EVENT 2: " << event.state << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    Event event;
    event.state = "something";

    //Doesn't really simplify anything, still two template arugments
    registerEvent<Event, &OnEvent2>();

    //I want to convert to something like: 
    // registerEventSmall(&OnEvent);
    // registerEventSmall<&OnEvent>();

    //Trying to get to this
    dispatcher.sink<Event>().connect<&OnEvent>();

    dispatcher.trigger<Event>(std::move(event));
}
```

registerEventSmall is the function I'm trying to get work and the two commented out functions in main are what I'm trying to achieve.

Is this possible?
How can I achieve the simplification?

Comment: Please create a [mre] and include all relevant source code in the question itself.  External links rot (even Godbolt).

Comment: @PaulSanders should be fixed

Comment: Not really.  I can't compile and run this code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509273/get-types-of-c-function-parameters do you need sth like this?

Comment: Are `Func` and `OnEvent` meant to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

You might do

```
template <auto fnPtr>
void registerEventSmall() {
    return []<typename EventType>(void(*)(const EventType&)){
        registerEvent<EventType,fnPtr >();
    }(fnPtr);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G93oW56jc)