# C++ gets the first parameter type of a function type?

Tags: c++

For a function pointer of unknown type, how to obtain the type of its first parameter.

```cpp
template<auto Callable>
void callFunction() {
    // using ArgType = First argument type from Callable
    // expect: ArgType == int*
}

int main() {
    callFunction<[](int*) {}>();
    return 0;
}
```

Reason: I hope to implement a RAII(like std::unique_ptr) type that automatically calls the destructor, as follows. This type requires two template parameters, but the first parameter should be deducible from the second parameter, so how can I omit the first template parameter?

```cpp
#include <utility>

template <typename DataType, void (*DestoryFunc)(DataType*)>
class raii_t {
private:
    DataType* m_data;

public:
    explicit raii_t(DataType* data) noexcept
        : m_data(data) {
    }

    raii_t(const raii_t&) = delete;
    auto operator=(const raii_t&) -> raii_t& = delete;

    raii_t(raii_t&& other) noexcept
        : m_data(std::exchange(other.m_data, nullptr)) {
    }

    auto operator=(raii_t&& other) noexcept -> raii_t& {
        if (m_data) {
            DestoryFunc(m_data);
        }
        m_data = std::exchange(other.m_data, nullptr);
        return *this;
    }

    ~raii_t() {
        if (m_data) {
            DestoryFunc(m_data);
        }
    }

    auto get() noexcept {
        return m_data;
    }

    auto release() noexcept {
        return std::exchange(m_data, nullptr);
    }

    auto reset(DataType* data) {
        if (m_data) {
            DestoryFunc(m_data);
        }
        m_data = data;
    }
};
auto destory(int*) {}

int main() {
    // now
    auto raii = raii_t<int, destory>(nullptr);

    // expect
    // auto raii = raii_t<destory>(nullptr);

    // expect or
    // auto raii = raii_t(nullptr, destory);

    return 0;
}
```

It would be better if both template parameters could be omitted and the constructor passed a function pointer. But this seems unlikely, I don't want to store the function pointer into the class, which would increase the occupied type space.

c++20

Comment: You need to use a parameter pack for your arguments something like this `template<typename fn_t, typename... args_t> auto callFunction(fn_t fn, args_t... args) { return fn(std::forward<args_t>(args)...); }`

Comment: I cannot use "parameter packs" because it would prevent me from calling that function in a member function of a class without storing pointers.

Comment: This is bad API design. If you try to deduce the parameter type, then templates and overloaded functions breaks down. Furthermore, the standard library already have an API for this very specific purpose (i.e. deleters) that everyone expects, so your custom API will only confuse people.

Comment: Then resort to letting you function accept lambdas and let then do all the heavy lifting for you.  `template <typename fn_t> auto callFunction(fn_t fn) { return fn(); }` and call with `callFunction([](int*){ ... });` .. In the end I think there is no need to "reinvent the wheel"

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/28509273/4117728

Comment: what is your `raii_t` doing that `std::unique_ptr` cannot do already?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai `std::unique_ptr` always calls `delete m_data`, but I want to call `close_function(m_data)`.

Comment: thats not true. `std::unique_ptr<T,Deleter>` calls the `Deleter` when it goes out of scope

Comment: for details see here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: With partial specialization, you don't need a dedicated traits, i.e `template <auto* f> class raii_t;
template <typename DataType, void (*F)(DataType*)>
class raii_t<F>{/*as before*/};` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/36WYqdoWc) (requires C++17).